ansible / jinja, adding key values from one dict list into another dict list if one key value matches in both
I'm trying to get key values from one dict list and insert them into the dictionaries on another dict list if one of the keys match jinja is not liking this.
using ansible-core 2.15.11 with community.general and posix collections on rhel 7 using python 3.9.19
dict liet 1
"vcenterinfo": [
        {
            "AZ": "a",
            "POD": "11",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        },
        {
            "AZ": "b",
            "POD": "09",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV09"
        }
]

dict list 2:
"provdata": [
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        },
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV09"
        },
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        }
    ]


Any help greatley appreciated.
Desired results:

"provdata": [
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
            "AZ": "a",
            "POD": "11"
        },
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV09",
            "AZ": "b",
            "POD": "09"
        },
        {
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
            "AZ": "a",
            "POD": "11"
        }
    ]
     

I tried this first and iet just errors out
 provdata: "{{ provdata + [{ item | combine({'AZ':, vcenterinfo | selectattr('VCENTERNAME', 'equalto', 'item.VCENTER') | map(attribute='AZ') | list}) }] }}"

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected ','. String: {{ provdata + [{ item | combine({'AZ':, vcenterinfo | selectattr('VCENTERNAME', 'equalto', 'item.VCENTER') | map(attribute='AZ') | list}) }] }}. unexpected ','"}

I then tried this but the AZ values is empty and looks to be a list
- name: Create a new list
  vars:
    azdata: "{{ item | combine({AZ: vcenterinfo | selectattr(VCENTERNAME, equalto, item.VCENTERNAME) | map(attribute=AZ) }) }}"
  set_fact:
    list4: "{{ list4 | default([]) + [azdata] }}"
  loop: "{{ provdata }}"
 
 
"list4": [
        {
            "AZ": [],
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        },
        {
            "AZ": [],
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV09"
        },
        {
            "AZ": [],
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        }
    ]



"I tried this first and iet just errors out"...that's because there was a syntax error in your expression.

You could this with a custom filter plugin. Drop the following into filter_plugins/filters.py:
def merge_on_key(v, updates, key):
    for item in v:
        for update in updates:
            if update[key] == item[key]:
                item.update(update)

    return v


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"merge_on_key": merge_on_key}

And then write your playbook like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        provdata: "{{ provdata | merge_on_key(vcenterinfo, 'VCENTERNAME') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ provdata }}"

Given the example data in your question, this will output:
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "AZ": "a",
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "POD": "11",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        },
        {
            "AZ": "b",
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "POD": "09",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV09"
        },
        {
            "AZ": "a",
            "CLUSTER": "XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX",
            "DEDICATED": "false",
            "EnvironMent": "test",
            "POD": "11",
            "TIER": "silver",
            "VCENTERNAME": "XGM1AQV11"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   




Convert the vcenterinfo list to a dictionary

  v_dict: "{{ dict(vcenterinfo |
                   json_query('[].[VCENTERNAME, @]')) }}"

gives
  v_dict:
    XGM1AQV09:
      AZ: b
      POD: 09
      VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV09
    XGM1AQV11:
      AZ: a
      POD: '11'
      VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11


Get the list of the keys and extract the values from the dictionary

  update: "{{ provdata |
              json_query('[].VCENTERNAME') |
              map('extract', v_dict) }}"

gives
  update:
  - AZ: a
    POD: '11'
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11
  - AZ: b
    POD: 09
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV09
  - AZ: a
    POD: '11'
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11


zip the update and combine the items

  result: "{{ provdata | zip(update) | map('combine') }}"

gives
  - AZ: a
    CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX
    DEDICATED: 'false'
    EnvironMent: test
    POD: '11'
    TIER: silver
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11
  - AZ: b
    CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX
    DEDICATED: 'false'
    EnvironMent: test
    POD: 09
    TIER: silver
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV09
  - AZ: a
    CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX
    DEDICATED: 'false'
    EnvironMent: test
    POD: '11'
    TIER: silver
    VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    vcenterinfo:
      - {AZ: a, POD: '11', VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11}
      - {AZ: b, POD: '09', VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV09}

    provdata:
      - CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C4-NTNX
        DEDICATED: 'false'
        EnvironMent: test
        TIER: silver
        VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11
      - CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C5-NTNX
        DEDICATED: 'false'
        EnvironMent: test
        TIER: silver
        VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV09
      - CLUSTER: XGM1AQV11-C6-NTNX
        DEDICATED: 'false'
        EnvironMent: test
        TIER: silver
        VCENTERNAME: XGM1AQV11

    v_dict: "{{ dict(vcenterinfo |
                     json_query('[].[VCENTERNAME, @]')) }}"
    update: "{{ provdata |
                json_query('[].VCENTERNAME')|map('extract', v_dict) }}"
    result: "{{ provdata | zip(update) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: v_dict
    - debug:
        var: update
    - debug:
        var: result


